# Replace unicode escaped string with their representation

Tags: regex

For example, I have a text string like this: `\u041c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\` (it's literally like that) and I want to replace those escapes with their text representation by regex, and I don't know if it's possible.

I tried this:

match: `\\u(....)`
replace: `\x\1`

And I did get this result: `_0@B8` (`_` is actually empty space, but it disappears in markdown)

I was pleasently surprised that I even got some transformation result out of it, as I honestly didn't thought it was possible to do this.

This is perl compatible engine built in a tool I use.

Comment: Have you tried replacing with `\x{\1}`?

Comment: yes, I tried that first as read here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html but that didn't worked, as I got literal curly brackets in output

Comment: Then I think you'll need to be more specific than just "a tool I use".

Comment: It's find/replace dialog in UE editor, which supposedly supports this regex engines: 1.Perl, 2. Unix, 3. built-in

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
use Encode qw(encode);

$_ = '\u041c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438';
s/\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/{ encode('utf8', chr($1)) }/ige;
```